# What types of indexing does Neo4j use for schema index?

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I am new to Neo4j when I came across Neo4j indexes, all what I found is that there's a legacy index and another new one (the schema index), but I want to know what are the types of these indexes and if there's a way to specify it ? i.e in oracle we have clustered/non-clustered/b-tree/bitmap ...etc , do we have something similar in Neo4j?

Comment: if interested @khaled-adel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Neo4j there is two kinds of index :

- Schema indexes (via create index or create constraint)
- Legacy indexes

All those indexes are internally made with Lucene, and there is no type of indexe, like in oracle.

When you use legacy indexes, you can configure them like it's describe here  : http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html

You can find some additional informations here :

- http://jexp.de/blog/2015/04/on-neo4j-indexes-match-merge/
- http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2013/12/indexing-in-neo4j-an-overview/

Cheers